# Using SQL Alchemy orm query for the average between dates

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

How would you express the query below in sql alchemy's orm syntax?  It's easy to do basic sum/avg/counts on single columns, however when trying to get the average span between a series of dates I can't seem to get the orm syntax to work.

Select AVG(completion_date - queue_date) as avg_duration 
from product_work_queue where task_id = 1

note that there are multiple entries in product_work_queue for each task id. The back-end database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

```
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(
    func.avg(MyClass.completion_date - MyClass.queue_date).label('avg_duration')
 ).\
    filter(MyClass.task_id == 1)
```